# Что обозначает переменная Node<E> next?

Tags: java

Дело в том, что класс Node является вложенным в другой класс, и я не могу понять, что означает запись 
private Node next;
Это создание объекта класса в самом классе, или как?

```
public static class Node<E>{
        private E currentEl;
        private Node<E> next;
        private Node<E> prev;

        public Node(E currentEl, Node<E> prev, Node<E> next){
            this.currentEl = currentEl;
            this.next = next;
            this.prev = prev;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Это переменная, что хранит ссылку на объект. Объект уже будет создан и передан в конструктор `Node`

Comment: Объекты создаются с помощью ключевого слова `new`. Переменные хранят ссылки на объекты. В классе Node объявлены два поля для хранения ссылок на следующий Node и предыдущий Node. По умолчанию переменным присваивается значение `null`, означающее, что переменная не хранит ссылку ни на какой объект. В конструктор передаются объекты, ссылки на которые будут сохранены в полях.